# Can't find the definition of ずっきり

Tags: meaning

I haven't been able to find the definition of ずっきり in any dictionary.

A few examples:

- 今のほうがずっきりしてて好きです。([source](https://twitter.com/petersaka/status/6736529296728064))
- しかしどうもずっきりしない。 ([source](https://www.ujc.ritsumei.ac.jp/ujc/student_act/club/baseball/baseball.newtopics.10.4.html))
- ずっきり雨の日は腰が痛い、リュウマチか ([source](http://ameblo.jp/tsujido55/entry-12136561077.html))
- 「何も御会計と御相談さ。」と、ずっきり言う。 ([source](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=qflJEjBJ-MQC&pg=PT14&lpg=PT14&dq=%22%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8A%22&source=bl&ots=bhj2splWPJ&sig=IDDrlMQaghmRedJtl0-YQbc5vP0&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqqqHN8pfNAhVKFpQKHcvODKoQ6AEIYjAN#v=onepage&q=%22%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8A%22&f=false))

It can seem to be a verb because it is sometimes attached with する, した, して, etc.

By the way, is ずつきり the typographical error of ずっきり?

Comment: The word is very rare. In the Google Japanese N-Gram corpus there are only 135 instances of ずっきり. To put this in perspective, there are 5767407 instances すっきり.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The first two ずっきり must be simple typo for [すっきり](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%99%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8A) (refreshing, clear, organized, etc). I haven't heard anyone say ずっきり for this purpose.
- The third ずっきり is a variant of [ズキズキ](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%BA%E3%82%AD%E3%82%BA%E3%82%AD) or ズキリズキリ (mimetics for throbbing pain). See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/28926/5010).
- I'm not sure about the last ずっきり. Maybe it's a variant of [ずけずけ](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%9A%E3%81%91%E3%81%9A%E3%81%91) (bluntly)? It must be very rare anyway... I think you can safely forget this example.

Answer (score 1):

Judging also from the sentences you report, it seems to me probably just either a typo or a colloquial/dialectal way to say すっきり.

EDIT：　I actually read only the first two examples in your question and replied right away. I am not sure about the third and forth cases, could be something different.

Comment: Now I am wondering why the downvote..